# "Expected host key was not configured, use -hostkey switch" when using WinSCP to SFTP

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

I have requirement of uploading the .csv file to SFTP. I have got a .ppk file

My WinSCP script:

```
open sftp://ex@ex.com/ -privatekey=ssh.ppk
lcd Z:\TR TEM DATA\
cd /home/cli/mm/gns
ascii
put -transfer=ascii -latest *.csv
exit
```

Error:

```
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Expected host key was not configured, use -hostkey switch
```

The log file also contains:

Error in the file :

```
Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
```

Can someone please advise

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `open` command is missing [`-hostkey` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey), as the error message hints you.

See:

- [Verifying the host key in script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey)
- [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)

---

The easiest solution is to have [WinSCP GUI generate a script template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

---

*Btw, you problem has nothing to do with .ppk/private key. See [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).*

Comment: The second link shows a way to use WinSCP to generate a script with the correct syntax, encoding, and hostkey. Very useful! Thank you!